# Event listener to capture what would've been input by keyboard entry?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I am working with vanilla JavaScript/HTML/CSS. No framework or anything fancy like that.

I am making a typing speed game. The user is presented a paragraph which they need to type. This is what my HTML would look like if you were presented with "Hello World!".

```
<div id="typing_window" tabindex="1">
  <span id="element0">H</span>
  <span id="element1">e</span>
  <span id="element2">l</span>
  <span id="element3">l</span>
  <span id="element4">o</span>
  <span id="element5">&nbsp;</span>
  <span id="element6">W</span>
  <span id="element7">o</span>
  <span id="element8">r</span>
  <span id="element9">l</span>
  <span id="element10">d</span>
  <span id="element11">!</span>
</div>
```

I would like to add an event listener to capture what would have been input by the keyboard. For example, the first character is a capital H, so if the user presses shift+h or capslock+h on the keyboard, the event listener handle function should return an "H", which I can compare to the next character in the paragraph. The same function also needs to correctly capture spaces and any special characters like !.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well you could just use a regular keyup event, and either access the "key" property, or make your own map of results corresponding to the key code, with "" s n front for shift.

Quick example
var map={"s45": "H"/*no idea if actual key, just example*/}
addEventListener("keyup", e=> {
var key="";
if(e.shiftKey) key+="s"
key += e.keyCode
var mapt=map[key]
// Do something

})